# How I can build a string from the Title values return from Get Items action?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have a Get Item action to return list items. then I want to build a comma separated string for all the titles. I tried this:

```
join(outputs('Get_items')?['body/value']?['Title'],';')'
```

and this:

```
join(outputs('Get_items')?[Title],';')
```

but it did not work. any advice?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do it using `join` function. You will have to do it using apply to each loop.

Comment: @GaneshSanap even if i try to use select?

Comment: You can use select to create an array in this format: `['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3']`. Then you can use join function. Let me add one example in answer.

Comment: check below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flow like this:

[image]

Expression in compose action:

```
join(body('Select'), ';')
```

**Output**:

[image]